# In Laravel what is the best method to save or store data in database

Tags: laravel-4

For usual Form like the following form I use the following technique to save data into database.

// Controller

```
public function store()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Person::$rules);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        Person::create($data);
        return Redirect::route('admin.person.index');
    }
```

But in my this form there is an file input field where user can upload multiple files at a time. and I want to store the files name into database i,e 
image-1, image-2, image-3 like this. I am trying to use image intervention package to handle image files. But in that case what would my code to store data into database.

// Form

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('admin.index.store'), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true)) }}

    <li>
          {{ Form::label('name', 'Index Name') }}
          {{ Form::text('name', null, array( 'class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Name' )) }}
          {{ $errors->first('name', '<p class="error">:message</p>' ) }}
    </li>


    <li>
          {{ Form::label('phone_number', 'Phone Number') }}
          {{ Form::text('phone_number', null, array( 'class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Phone Number' )) }} 
          {{ $errors->first('phone_number', '<p class="error">:message</p>' ) }}
    </li>


    <li>
           {{ Form::label('image', 'Profile Picture') }}
           {{ Form::file('files[]', array('id' => 'files', 'multiple' => true)); }}

    </li>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Person::create($data); this wont fly.

You have to parse Input from forms, remove Files, process files separatelly and then update filepath with

```
//code to get $dataWithoutfiles;
$person = Person::create($dataWithoutFiles);
//code to save files to local
$person->file1 = 'path1';
// 2,3,4, etc.
 $person->save();
```